# How can I compare the lowest value with the previous and next value in a row in an array?

Tags: python

How can I find the lowest value in each column for each row?

I tried to compare the next value with the next value but i don´t know how to compare the current value with all the lowest values in each row

```
import csv
import numpy as geek

results = []

with open('INSTANCES/M1.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
  #change contents to float
  csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) 
  #Each row is in a list
  for row in csv_reader:
    results.append(row)
print("\nArray in CSV file: " + str(results) + "\n")

intResults = []
matrix=[]
minFila =1000
z = []
g=[]

for i in range(0, len(results)):
  intResults.append([])
for i in range(0, len(results)):
  for j in range(0, len(results[i])):
    intResults[i].append(int(results[i][j]))
matrix.append(geek.asarray(intResults))
#print(f"\n {matrix}")

for a in matrix:
    z = geek.array(a)
print(f"{z}\n")


for m in range(0, len(z)):
  for n in range(0, len(z[m])):
    if z[m][n]<minFila:
      minFila = z[m][n]
  #g.append(minFila)
  if z[m][n]+1<minFila:
    minFila = z[m][n]+1
  g.append(minFila)
  minFila = 10000
  

#print(g)

b = geek.argwhere(z<=g[:])
print(f"The position of the lowest values are: {b}\n")
print(f"The values of the lowest positions are: {g}")
```

The code read a csv file in which the array is:

```
[[ 77  17  41  42]
 [ 79  66  28  26]
 [100  21  75  24]
 [ 87  32  41  80]]
```

## The answer of the lowest value in each column for each row should be:

Positions and values:

```
[[0,1]
[1,2] 
[2,3] 
[3,0]]
[17, 28, 24, 87]
```

But the answer that I got was:

```
[[0 1] 
 [1 3]
 [2 1]
 [2 3]]
[17, 26, 21, 32]
```

Comment: You just want the lowest value per row?

Comment: Yes, but once I have the first lowest value, I have to compare that value in the others rows to see which one is the lowest of them. Then I have to reassing the position of each lowest value because I have to optimize the " time" of each Machine per each task (column per row)